# One master page used by three pages CSS problems

Tags: css, html, master-pages

I have one master page that is used for three pages. Thats how its going to be I cant do anything about it. This master page generate a class element that have a background color of white. I want to have it white on one of the pages and black on another.

But the problem is that both pages use same master page which means I cant specify to have different color. The pages are generated by a hive which means that I cant edit the pages. I can only use the css file and the master page.

Any kind of help is very appreciated

Comment: but master-pages are meant to be used for common layout of multiple pages. if you have something uncommon for a given page, css it there iteself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could detect somehow the page id/name that uses the master would be ok. 
Or using javascript take your url and compare it, so if it's the first page apply inline style for black and if not leave it white.

Comment: Hmm I have a <form method> that have a action value that contains the current url like <form method action="url/url/default.aspx">

Comment: if your class that generates that white background is inside your form with that atribute you could make it simply from css with
form[action=url/url/default.aspx] .classforblack {background:black !important;}

Answer (score 0):

if you can add some inline css

body {

background:  ;

}